# Why is my NSTextField not responding to setStringValue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-bindings

I have an object which is hooked up to interface builder (one of the little blue boxes down the left hand side (Xcode 4.5.2) and I have created bindings to an NSTextField as I am used to doing. I have also synthesised the text field in the main file (don't quite understand why but pretty sure this is necessary). However, when I try sending setStringValue:@"a string" to the text field, it doesn't work. Also, when I try and print the text field object to the command line it says null. From googling, I think some people have this problem when they use init instead of awakefromnib but this method in my programme is triggered when I press a button. The code is below. If any more information is needed, let me know. Thanks.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CSSRuleSet.h"

@interface RuleSetViewUpdater : NSObject
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *top;

-(void)updateFields:(CSSRuleSet *)RuleSet;


@end
```

.

```
#import "RuleSetViewUpdater.h"

@implementation RuleSetViewUpdater

@synthesize top = _top;

-(void)updateFields:(CSSRuleSet *)RuleSet
{
    [_top setStringValue:[RuleSet getValue:@"top"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", _top);
}

@end
```

xib structure

[image]

Comment: Is the outlet set? You should have a circle before the line number of `@property` with a dot in it).

Comment: Yep!.. I have set things up exactly as I'm used to. I imagine that the problem comes from the interface loading after the code somehow but I have no idea how this happens/how I can solve this.

Comment: Can you add a screen dump of your xib structure - the outline view on the left of IB?

Comment: Yeah sure. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with ownership of the interface - I'm afraid I'm not too advanced when it comes to objective c development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I realised what I was doing wrong. Basically, I had connected up the interface builder to the object exactly fine and it would of worked but because of the nature of my programme, I was initialising a new object to control the interface not realising that by doing that it would not have access to the interface. So basically instead I had to pass the original object. That probably does not make any sense but let me know if it needs explaining better.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a connection from your sourcefile to the object in the XIB file. You have an outlet defined, but it's not sure that it's actually connected. Right-click on the object in the XIB file and make sure the outlet is connected.

Your NSLog statement ( NSLog(@"%@", _top); ) logs the NSTextField object itself. The fact that it logs "(null)", means that the outlet is not (yet) connected. When your XIB file gets loaded, the outlets are not immediately connected. awakeFromNib() gets called on all the objects in the XIB file when the file is loaded. After this, you should be able to access the objects by using the outlets.